# How to obtain the n-th letter of the alphabet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a short formula to get the n-th letter of the alphabet?

For example, if I give parameter `5` to the function, I would get the letter `e`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a function `CHAR` which gives a character with the specified code:

```
CHAR(96 + 5)
```

will yield your "e".

But there is no direct way to get a character of the alphabet.

Comment: And CHAR(64+n) will get the nth letter in uppercase.

Answer (score 3):

An alternate, although not as short as the **CHAR** function, is the **CHOOSE** function

```
=CHOOSE(5,"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","I","j","k","l","m",
        "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z")
```

The index number **'5'** returns the fifth value in the list.  The list could be an Excel range of data e.g. (A1:A26).

If the index number is outside the range, **#VALUE!** is returned

Answer (score 1):

you could use an ascii function since every letter has a numeric value in ascii

Not sure what language your using... in T-SQL you can use an ASCII and CHAR functions:

PRINT CHAR(ASCII('A') + @i) -- where @i is your numeric value

Answer (score 1):

There is also another simpler way: `CHAR(CODE("A")+TRUNC(RAND()*26))`.

Comment: This does not answer the given question; instead, it generates a random uppercase letter.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the position of the letter in question (C3, for example) if it is capital or not.

```
=IF(AND(CODE(C3)>=65,CODE(C3)<=90),CODE(C3)-64,IF(AND(CODE(C3)>=97,CODE(C3)<=122),CODE(C3)-96,"Error"))
```

Comment: This does not answer the given question; instead, it goes the other way. Given a _letter_, it will return a _number_ indicating that letter's position relative to the start of the alphabet, regardless of case. (And it would be easier to force the letter to upper or lower case to start.)